# Check Box para chamar função que troca língua

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Estou com uma dúvida em uma tela `.aspx` que gera um relatório em grid e preciso fazer com que ao dar check em um checkbox e clicar no botão **Gerar** o relatório seja gerado em Inglês.

Para gerar esse relatório tenho uma classe relatórios que contém uma `function GerarRelatorioSg`, nessa função eu já faço um tratamento de idioma. Caso a linguagem do usuário seja Inglês nativo, tudo que eu preciso em Inglês é por meio de um `If Idioma = 2 then`

Código completo da Function

```
Function GerarRelatorioSg(ByVal dtini As String, ByVal dtfim As String, ByVal TipoData As Integer, ByVal cdConcessionario As Integer, ByVal cdLaudo As String, ByVal Idioma As Integer, ByVal perfil As Integer) As DataTable

        Dim sSql As System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim dt As DataTable

        Dim dbgar As New DBProvider
        Dim dberp As New DBProvider

        Try

            dbgar.Abrir(DBProvider.enConnectionType.GARANTIA)

            If TipoData = 3 Then

                sSql = New System.Text.StringBuilder
                sSql.Append(" update garantia a set ")
                sSql.Append(" a.dt_entrada = (select min(x.dt_laudo) from garantia x where nu_sg = a.nu_sg and x.cd_laudo=3) ")
                sSql.Append(" where ")
                sSql.Append(" a.dt_exclusao is null and ")
                sSql.Append(" a.dt_entrada is null ")
                dbgar.ExecuteNonQuery(sSql.ToString)

                sSql = New System.Text.StringBuilder
                sSql.Append(" update garantia a set ")
                sSql.Append(" a.dt_entrada = (select min(x.dt_laudo) from garantia x where nu_sg = a.nu_sg and x.cd_laudo in (7,11,13,14)) ")
                sSql.Append(" where ")
                sSql.Append(" a.dt_exclusao is null and ")
                sSql.Append(" a.dt_entrada is null ")
                dbgar.ExecuteNonQuery(sSql.ToString)

            End If

            sSql = New System.Text.StringBuilder
            sSql.Append(" SELECT ")
            sSql.Append("           g.nu_oc, ")
            sSql.Append("           g.nu_ordem_servico, ")
            sSql.Append("           g.cd_tipo_garantia, ")
            sSql.Append("           g.nu_nd, ")
            sSql.Append("           g.nu_chassi, ")
            sSql.Append("           g.nu_quilometros, ")
            sSql.Append("           to_char((select min(dt_inclusao) from garantia where nu_sg = g.nu_sg), 'yyyy/mm/dd') as dt_inclusao, ")
            sSql.Append("           g.vl_pecas, ")
            sSql.Append("           g.vl_maodeobra, ")
            sSql.Append("           g.vl_servico, ")
            sSql.Append("           g.vl_total, ")
            If Idioma = 2 Then
                sSql.Append("           w.nm_perfil1_idioma2 as nm_perfil1,")
            Else
                sSql.Append("           w.nm_perfil1,")
            End If
            sSql.Append("           to_char(g.dt_laudo,'yyyy/mm/dd') as dt_laudof, ")
            sSql.Append("           c.sg_concessionario, ")
            sSql.Append("           cr.cd_regiao, ")
            sSql.Append("           gp.cd_peca, ")

            If Idioma = 2 Then
                sSql.Append("           p.ds_peca_idioma2 as nm_peca, ")
            Else
                sSql.Append("           p.ds_peca_idioma1 as nm_peca, ")
            End If


            sSql.Append("           g.ds_reclamacao,")
            sSql.Append("           g.ds_diagnostico,")
            sSql.Append("           g.ds_reparo,")
            sSql.Append("           to_char(g.dt_falha,'yyyy/mm/dd') as dt_falha,")
            sSql.Append("           to_char(g.dt_reclamacao,'yyyy/mm/dd') as dt_reclamacao,")
            sSql.Append("           null as dt_compensa, ")
            sSql.Append("           v.ds_modelo, ")
            sSql.Append("           v.cd_modelo_garantia, ")

            If Idioma = 2 Then
                sSql.Append("           (select distinct upper(vl_dominio||'-'||ds_dominio_idioma2) as cd_problema from dominio where id_tipo_dominio = 41 and dt_exclusao is null and vl_dominio = g.cd_falha) as cd_problema, ")
                sSql.Append("           (select distinct upper(vl_dominio||'-'||ds_dominio_idioma2) as cd_problema from dominio where id_tipo_dominio = 42 and dt_exclusao is null and vl_dominio = g.cd_consequencia) cd_defeito, ")
            Else
                sSql.Append("           (select distinct upper(vl_dominio||'-'||ds_dominio_idioma1) as cd_problema from dominio where id_tipo_dominio = 41 and dt_exclusao is null and vl_dominio = g.cd_falha) as cd_problema, ")
                sSql.Append("           (select distinct upper(vl_dominio||'-'||ds_dominio_idioma1) as cd_problema from dominio where id_tipo_dominio = 42 and dt_exclusao is null and vl_dominio = g.cd_consequencia) cd_defeito, ")
            End If

            sSql.Append("           to_char(g.dt_aprovacao, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as dt_aprovacao, ")
            sSql.Append("           (select distinct ds_nome from usuario where dt_exclusao is null and id_usuario=g.cd_usuario_inc and id_perfil=1) as nm_analista ")
            sSql.Append(" FROM  ")
            sSql.Append("           garantia g, garantia_pc gp, workflow w, concessionario c, veiculo v, peca p, concessionario_regiao cr ")
            sSql.Append(" WHERE ")
            sSql.Append("           c.dt_exclusao is null ")
            sSql.Append("           and g.dt_exclusao is null ")
            sSql.Append("           and gp.dt_exclusao is null ")
            sSql.Append("           and cr.dt_exclusao is null ")
            sSql.Append("           and g.nu_chassi = v.nu_chassi ")
            sSql.Append("           and g.cd_concessionario = c.id_concessionario ")
            sSql.Append("           and g.cd_concessionario = cr.cd_concessionario ")
            sSql.Append("           and g.cd_laudo = w.cd_laudo ")
            sSql.Append("           and g.nu_ordem_servico = gp.nu_ordem_servico")
            sSql.Append("           and g.nu_seq_ordem_servico = gp.nu_seq_ordem_servico")
            sSql.Append("           and g.cd_concessionario = gp.cd_concessionario")
            sSql.Append("           and gp.cd_peca = p.cd_peca ")
            sSql.Append("           and gp.cd_tipo = 1")
            sSql.Append("           and w.id_processo = 4 ")

            If cdConcessionario > 0 Then
                sSql.Append("       and g.cd_concessionario = " & cdConcessionario)
            End If

            If cdLaudo.Length > 0 Then
                sSql.Append("       and g.cd_laudo in (" & cdLaudo & ")")
            End If

            If dtini.Trim.Length > 0 AndAlso dtfim.Trim.Length > 0 Then
                If TipoData = 1 Then
                    sSql.Append("       and g.dt_reclamacao between ")
                ElseIf TipoData = 2 Then
                    sSql.Append("       and g.dt_laudo between ")
                ElseIf TipoData = 3 Then
                    sSql.Append("       and (select min(dt_inclusao) from garantia where nu_sg = g.nu_sg) between ")
                End If
                sSql.Append("       to_date('" & dtini & " 00:00:00','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') ")
                sSql.Append("       and to_date('" & dtfim & " 23:59:59','yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')")
            End If

            sSql.Append("           order by g.dt_laudo ")

            dt = dbgar.CreateDataTable(sSql.ToString)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex)

        Finally

            dbgar.FecharConexao()
            dberp.FecharConexao()

        End Try
        Return dt

    End Function
```

Caso o usuário esteja com um perfil nativo Português e queira gerar o Relatório em Inglês, é selecionado o check box

Para fazer o check box funcionar eu faço o seguinte

```
if chkIngles.checked = true then


end if
```

Eu não sei o que colocar nesse último `If`

Como eu faço pra chamar esse Idioma da classe GerarRelatorioSg e deixa-lo como padrão 2 caso o chkIngles.checked = true ?

Comment: Oi, Igor, bemvindo ao [pt.so]. Tentei dar um título descritivo à sua pergunta, mas acho que sua dúvida não está muito clara... Como assim, *"entre os `()`"*? Você se refere a parâmetros da função? Você é livre para [edit] a pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes.

Comment: Olá brasofilo, muito obrigado.
O que pretendo fazer é um modo de chamar o Idioma para esse if fazendo com que caso o checked = true o idioma seja 2, assim não preciso mudar nada na classe. Mas não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: Na verdade, não conheço a linguagem, mas desconfio que é necessário que você mostre mais código (a função completa ou quase, no caso). Confira o guia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/201)

Comment: Irei editar pra melhorar o entendimento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gente consegui resolver esse problema.

Estou chamando o `Idioma = 2` desse jeito

```
If chkIngles.Checked = True Then
                dt = oRel.GerarRelatorioSg(Me.txtdtinicio.Text, Me.txtdtfim.Text, tpdata, idconcessionario, laudo, 2, CInt(Session("idperfil")))
            Else
                dt = oRel.GerarRelatorioSg(Me.txtdtinicio.Text, Me.txtdtfim.Text, tpdata, idconcessionario, laudo, Session("idioma"), CInt(Session("idperfil")))
            End If
```

Aonde está `Session("idioma")`  no `else`, é substituído por 2 caso o `Checked = true`